# How can I pass the data of the sum of 5 different data from my db using controller in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am new to laravel 5.4 and I want to total sum of 5 different data from my db when I view an specific guest with id in the database? I can't get the sum or the total

Here's my code:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $forPayment = ForPayment::where('application_number', $id)->get()->last();

    if (empty($forPayment)) {
        Flash::error('For Payment not found');

        return redirect(route('forPayments.index'));
    }
    $inspection_fee = $forPayment->inspection_fee;
    $storage_fee = $forPayment->storage_fee;
    $cert_fee = $forPayment->cert_fee;
    $local_fee = $forPayment->local_fee;
    $others_fee = $forPayment->others_fee;

    $total_fee = $inspection_fee + $storage_fee + $cert_fee + $local_fee + $others_fee;

    return view('cashier-dashboard.paid.show')->with('forPayment', $forPayment, $total_fee);
}
```

Comment: you are not passing $total_fee as you need to pass that in with() alongwith 'forPayment'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return view('cashier-dashboard.paid.show',compact('forPayment','total_fee'));
```

try this

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you send `forPayment` to your view. But you're not sending the `$total_fee`. You need to have a second `with()` method or you need to send an array to the `with()` method. For example:

```
return view('cashier-dashboard.paid.show')
    ->with('forPayment', $forPayment)
    ->with('totalFee', $total_fee);
```

Or as an array:

```
return view('cashier-dashboard.paid.show')
    ->with(['forPayment' => $forPayment, 'totalFee' => $total_fee]);
```

With both examples you can use `$totalFee` in your view to get the total fee.